# Alternatives for selecting a column from an array in MySQL

Tags: mysql, arrays, ruby

What other ways are there to select a column from an array? `result.each { |x| puts x[1] }` doesn't seem to work. Here's my code:

```
require 'mysql2'

connect = Mysql2::Client.new(:host :username :password :database)

result = connect.query("SELECT * FROM sampletable WHERE name = 'Joshua'")
result.each { |x| puts x[1] }
```

Comment: can you explain why you want to iterate through that array and  what is your expected output. this will simply return value from index 1 in that is that the expected behavior?

Comment: Currently, it will puts the entire row. I would like to `puts mobile number` of the selected name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **array.map**  instead of **array.each**

lets say if you want to get all mobile_number from that result you can do following.

`result.map {|r| r['mobile_number'] }`

**Difference between `each` and `map` is as follows:**

`each` simply iterates over the given enumerable, running the block for each value. It discards the return value of the block, and each simply returns the original object it was called on

**whereas:**

`map` however, iterates over each element, using the return value of the block to populate a new array at each respective index and return that new array

we can also use `collect` which is same as map

Comment: `collect` is _exactly_ the same as `map` - they're aliases

Comment: Thank you, your code works perfectly fine. If I would like to return two columns? `result.map {|r| r['mobile_number'], r['address'] }` how would you do it?

Comment: **map** will return you a array as result so if you want to get more than one column just make it as nested array as follows: `result.map {|r| [r['mobile_number'], r['address']] }`, you can get a result by this and now you can manipulate based on your requirements. hope i answered you question.

Comment: or by this `result.map {|r| r['mobile_number'] AND r['address'] }`. Is there a difference on how it will work?

Comment: sorry can you be more elaborate what is your expected result. putting  **AND** between those will result in an error so are you trying concatenate both  ?

Comment: @VishalTajPM I would like to get two columns, mobile number and address

Comment: if you want to get 2 columns you can follow method which i showed in previous comment. like `result.map {|r| [r['mobile_number'], r['address']] }` will result something like `[['1st mobile number comes here',  '1st address comes here'], ['2nd mobile number comes here',  '2nd address comes here']]` if this is not expected result please update the question based on your actual requirement and also expected output.

Comment: @VishalTajPM Hi sorry for the delayed response. I've gotten [['1st mobile number comes here', '1st address comes here'], but the 2nd one is not shown. 
`information = result.map { |r| [r['mobile_number'], r['address']] }` \n
`p information` 

is something wrong?

Comment: can you please confirm query result. check the number of records you fetched using that query.